# XPath Wordpress Filtering

Tags: wordpress, xpath, filter

Basically, I am using a plugin to show real estate posts, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pg3Fj.png)

The XML has this data with LET DATE. So basically, I need to create properties when they reach this date. But I have no clue how to do the filtering because some properties have let dates in next 2 months and I do not want them to show.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NUTB.png)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you're talking about `WP All Import` plugin. You want to filter an `XML` file in order to show specific posts(where `LET_DATE_AVAILABLE` value is not set for the upcoming months).

AFAIK XPath support in `WP All Import` is very limited (version 1.0 only). To filter posts prior to the current date (`20200804`), you could try the following XPath expression (you need to adjust the beginning for e.g. "`//POSTS[/PROPERTIES/LET_DATE_AVAILABLE[....]]`").

But I'm pretty sure it won't work since we're using numerous functions (`number, translate, substring`).

Assuming you have these data :

```
<ROOT>
<LET_DATE_AVAILABLE>
  <![CDATA[ 2020-08-18 00:00:00 ]]>
</LET_DATE_AVAILABLE>
<LET_DATE_AVAILABLE>
  <![CDATA[ 2020-11-18 00:00:00 ]]>
</LET_DATE_AVAILABLE>
<LET_DATE_AVAILABLE>
  <![CDATA[ 2020-12-18 00:00:00 ]]>
</LET_DATE_AVAILABLE>
<LET_DATE_AVAILABLE>
  <![CDATA[ 2020-07-18 00:00:00 ]]>
</LET_DATE_AVAILABLE>
</ROOT>
```

XPath 1.0 expression (you need to manually input the current date) :

```
//LET_DATE_AVAILABLE[number(translate(substring(.,1,14),"-",""))<=20200804]
```

XPath 2.0 expression (it won't work at all. Just to show it might have been possible if the plugin could support XPath 2.0) :

```
//LET_DATE_AVAILABLE[number(translate(substring(.,1,14),"-",""))<=number(translate(substring(concat(current-date(),""),1,10),"-",""))]
```

Output in both cases, 1 node :

```
<LET_DATE_AVAILABLE>
 2020-07-18 00:00:00
</LET_DATE_AVAILABLE>
```

To make this works, I think your best option is to write your own import function in `PHP`. References :

- https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/custom-code/overview/
- https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/code-snippets/
- https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/action-reference/